# Big Commerce Custom variable

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to the Big commerce. I set up the store template but struck with the custom attribute display on the product page.

I am having 4 custom fields with every product on my big commerce store 
ie Feature 1,Feature 2,Feature 3,Pre Order date.

I want to have only Pre Order date on the product page. If i use %%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%% its calling all 4 custom attributes on the product, but I want to display only Pre Order date custom filed value on the page.

Is their is any way to call just one custom variable on the page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the `%%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%%` file and add the `%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%` as a class to the DetailRow div. This way, you can use CSS to hide all the custom fields, and target the specific Pre Order Date custom field you'd like to display based on the addition of the custom field's name class.

```
<div class="DetailRow %%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%">
    <div class="Label">%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%:</div>
    <div class="Value">
        %%GLOBAL_CustomFieldValue%%
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.DetailRow{
    display:none;
}
.DetailRow.Pre.Order.Date{
    display:block;
}
```